# silverlight in blend

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

hi 
im developing silverlight application 
but when i m trying to compile that file its going to browser
i need to execute without browser can you tell me alternate solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building An Out-of-Browser Client With Silverlight 3

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882515.aspx

Answer (score 0):

(1) Create a new or (2) Open the Silverlight application using Visual Studio 2008/2010. From the Solution Explorer, simply right-click the **Project** file, **Properties**, and the Properties page will show up. Under the **Silverlight** tab, check '**Enable running application out of the browser**'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi i tried in VS2008 but its not showing " Enable running application our of the browser " option in silverlight tab what i have to do please can you tel me

Comment: @naveensiva: Make sure you installed Silverlight 3 Tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 first.

Comment: i installed silverlight3 tools for visual studio2008 and set those options and when i start to debug it was showing the following error " cannot find the out-of-browser application for sample.xap . you need to run this application in your webbrowser " what can i do for that

Comment: @naveensiva: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/36175-How-can-you-implement-Silverlight-Out-Of.aspx